# true or false: the risk-neutral measure is useless in this situation

Tags: brownian-motion, risk-neutral-measure, asset-pricing, girsanov, geometric-brownian

[Example 2 of this Wiki article on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk-neutral_measure#Example_2_%E2%80%93_Brownian_motion_model_of_stock_prices) the risk-measure describes how a stock price $S_t$ that is modeled with Geometric Brownian motion with drift $\mu$
$$
dS_t = \mu S_t dt + \sigma S_t dW_t
$$
can be rewritten in a risk-neutral way so that the drift is the risk free interest rate $r$:

$$
dS_t = r S_t dt + \sigma S_t d \tilde{W}_t.
$$

My question is this:

> if I am an investor who is only buying/selling $S_t$ (no bonds, no derivatives, etc.), why should I care about this at all? How would this have any impact on my investment decisions?

Comment: The risk-neutral one is only for the valuation of derivatives by arbitrage. So no, if you are not working with derivatives you don't need to know about that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Risk-neutral pricing is to help with relative value type questions: If I know the value of this what should the value of that be if it depends in some way on this. It doesn't help with absolute value type questions: Should I buy this or that, is the implied volatility too low or high etc. Those are generally "real world measure" type questions.